# Fetching data in useEffect no re rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const Home = withRouter((props: RouteComponentProps) => {
  const [dataState, setDataState] = useState(data);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/');
      const parsed = await res.json();
      setDataState(parsed);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
....
```

I have this code to fetch some initial data for my component. The call is made, however it does not re-render until I actually interact with something in my UI. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Add complet code

Comment: Figured out the issue posted a solution

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the issue.

I was sorting the data in a child component. The effect there needed to depend on props.data passed from the home component.

```
  useEffect(() => {
     ...some sorting logic 
  }, [sortState, props.data]);

  return <Table minimalPadding={true} columns={columns} data={sortedData} />;
```